# icon inside textbox html css

Tags: html, css, textbox, icons

So, right now I have a registration form where a person has to enter their username, first name, last name etc.

I'm playing around with some CSS and thought it would be a nice idea to have some icons in the textboxes, however I cant seem to get it to work.

This is the code I have for the HTML:

```
<input id ="regtxt" type="text" placeholder="Username" name = "user" maxlength="9"/>
```

And this is the code that I have for the CSS:

```
#regtxt{
background-image:url('images/usericon.png');
left:no-repeat;
}
```

Any idea what I's doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it that does not work?

Comment: the icon doesnt seem to appear in the textbox

Comment: Does it appear at all?

Comment: No i cant see it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `left` and `no-repeat` are part of `background`.
Try this:

```
#regtxt{
   background-image:url('images/usericon.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

Make sure that the image/path is correct and no other css rule is overriding this.

Edit: try with an inline image:

```
#regtxt{
  background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7) right center no-repeat;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPgpKv

Comment: Then it's probably the image that can not be found. Try an inline image (changed the answer).

Comment: Still not working. I do have other css attached to that button:
input[type="email"], #regtxt, #regfn, #regln, #logtxt, input[type="password"]{
  width:92%;
  background:#fff;
  margin-bottom:4%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:4%;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-size:95%;
  color:#555;
}

Comment: If this other css comes after the css with the background image, then the image may be overwritten. Can you put your code in a codepen and post that?

Comment: And: use the inspector of your favorite browser to see what's going on and what finally ends up in the background property.

Comment: `background:#fff;` in `input[type="email"], #regtxt, #regfn, #regln, #logtxt, input[type="password"]` is overriding the `background-image`, because it comes later.

Quick fix would be to move the css with the background-image after this.
See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myzOXa

Comment: I'd advise to maybe work more with classes and make the rules not that specific.

Comment: I've used your solution with background:url( 'url'), without specifying the data. Thanks